# How to avoid mutating of a state variable in an Akka actor with inherited behavior?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-actor

I have some Akka actors with a common behavior. This common behavior is defined in a trait:

```
trait CommonBehavior {
  this: Actor =>
  var history: List[String] = Nil
  protected def commonActions: Receive = {
    case Action1 => history = "action1" :: history.take(99)
    case Action2 => history = "action2" :: history.take(99)
    case GetHistory => sender() ! history
  }
}
```

The actors override this trait and define additional behavior with `orElse`. This is one example of such actor:

```
class MyActor extends Actor with CommonBehavior {
  var state: Int = 0
  override def receive: Receive =
    commonActions orElse {
      case Increment => state += 1
      case Decrement => state -= 1
    }
}
```

I know that [mutating the state is an antipattern](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/5-actors.md#52-should-mutate-state-in-actors-only-with-contextbecome) and I want to refactor it with the usage of `context.become`. The problem is, when changing state in `MyActor` with `context.become`, I do not know the parameter for commonActions. Is it even possible to inherit behavior? Do I need a bigger refactor (e.g. creating a proxy actor)? This is how far I have got:

```
trait CommonBehavior {
  this: Actor =>
  protected def commonActions(history: List[String]): Receive = {
    case Action1 => context.become(??? orElse commonActions("action1" :: history.take(99))
    case Action2 => context.become(??? orElse commonActions("action2" :: history.take(99))
    case GetHistory => sender() ! history
  }
}

class MyActor extends Actor with CommonBehavior {
    override def receive = ready(0)
  def ready(state: Int): Receive = {
    case Increment => context.become(ready(state + 1) orElse commonActions(???))
    case Decrement => context.become(ready(state - 1) orElse commonActions(???))
  } orElse commonActions(Nil)
}
```

Comment: Take a look to the Akka Type´s immutable behaviors. Maybe it is the best and elegant way of solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Mutating state in an actor is not an antipattern, it is fine to do more OO style actors (and can in high througput cases be more performant) which mutate state in response to messages. Deciding to do a more FP-style is a personal preference so consider the pros and cons for your use case (your experience, team experience, project size, etc) rather than follow someones opinion dogmatically. Especially if you already have a class hierarchy that expects you to do mutations rather than switch behaviors.

If you decide you want to do a more FP-style actor, I'd recommend reconsidering the whole structure and not have a mixin with mutable state, requiring to be mixed in with an `Actor` to start with but design from that point of view. I'd also recommend going with the new typed APIs as the "FP:y" side of those gives a much nicer experience than using `become` with the classic Actor APIs.

Answer (score -2):

As I understood, you want to avoid state mutation within actor by changing the context of the actor. So, there are 2 possibilities:

1. If you are afraid to mutate the state within the actor, you can go with that as the mutation within the actor is fine and does not lead to concurrency issues. Its because actors work synchronously.
2. If you still want to keep the state immutable (val) and allow changing the state on runtime, you can do that using become. If you don't know the parameters for commonActions, you can either initialize it with a default value or pick the value from storage depending on business logic and then update accordingly.

Comment: There are many problems with this answer, not least that the question explicitly excludes your answer 1 and gives a link to explain why.